# Adding column names when exporting to excel in Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I have this code that downloads my table in excel format however the column names aren't shown so the data isn't readable by someone who doesn't know the database. Is there any way to add the column names to the excel document when downloaded?

Here is my code:

UsersExport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Models\Energy;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return Energy::all();
    }       
}
```

EnergyController

```
public function export()
    {
 return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'invoices.xlsx');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement WithHeadings, and define them as an array:

```
class UsersExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings {

      public function headings(): array {
          return [
              "name","mobile","email"
          ];
      }
```

..

check this example:
https://makitweb.com/export-data-in-excel-and-csv-format-with-laravel-excel/

Answer (score 0):

implements WithHeadings after FormCollection and defines headers.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Exports;
    use App\User;
    use App\Models\Models\Energy;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
    
    class UsersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
    {
        public function collection()
        {
            return Energy::all();
        }
    
        public function headings(): array
        {
            return ["First Name", "Last Name", "Contact", "Address", "Gender"];
        }
    }
```